# All of my crossdomain calls return with status 0 out of nowhere

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing using [kangoextensions](http://kangoextensions.com/), and have been for quite some time.

All of a sudden, every [kango.xhr](http://kangoextensions.com/docs/api-reference/kango-xhr.html) call, even to `bing.com`, instead of returning status 200, returns status 0 and "" for data. It happened 100% out of the blue. I tried it on multiple wi-fis (thanks, neighbor!), multiple machines, a VM with a VPN - nothing.

One second I was working another it's just all returns 0.

Blew my mind completely from the ground up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't assign the word "location" as a variable in javascript, it will break things quietly.